# Running asyncio tasks concurrently

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio

I'm just getting started to AsyncIO, but i'm having an hard time understanding some of the mechanics behind it. According to the docs, to run tasks concurrently, i need to use `asyncio.gather()`, so here is what i tried:

```
async def nested():
    BU = cfscrape.create_scraper()
    URL = "https://www.binance.com/api/v3/exchangeInfo"
    ResultRaw = BU.get(URL, timeout=(10, 15)).content
    Result = json.loads(ResultRaw)
    print('Done')
    return Result

async def main():
    await asyncio.gather(nested(), nested(), nested())

asyncio.run(main())
```

I expected this code to output `Done, Done, Done` at the same time, but instead it will execute the function synchronously. Why is that? Is it because i'm trying to execute synchronous code inside of `nested`?

Comment: The scraper you are using doesn't appear to support async execution - a telltale sign of a non-async function that just _looks_ async is that your `nested` function doesn't create a single `await`. You should switch a scraper that supports asyncio (or use aiohttp directly), then your approach will work as expected.

Comment: @user4815162342 Thank you a lot! It's much clearer now